# Searching for source code of coffee and scss methods

Tags: ruby, coffeescript, sinatra, sass, padrino

In my Sinatra/Padrino App I have

```
require 'sass'
require 'coffee-script'

# Routes to COFFEE-JS and SCSS-CSS
get '/javascripts/:name.js' do
  content_type 'text/javascript', charset: 'utf-8'
  coffee :"../../public/javascripts/coffee/#{params[:name]}"
end

get '/stylesheets/:name.css' do
  content_type 'text/css', charset: 'utf-8'
  scss :"../../public/stylesheets/scss/#{params[:name]}"
end
```

I want to know, where I can find definitions of methods **coffee** and **scss**. I want to learn source code of this methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @hugo said you can (I take coffee example) start from here:

https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L628

Then:

https://github.com/rtomayko/tilt/blob/master/lib/tilt/coffee.rb#L45

And finally:

https://github.com/rtomayko/tilt/blob/master/lib/tilt/coffee.rb#L45

https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs/blob/master/lib/execjs/runtime.rb#L43

Depending on your js runtime:

https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs/blob/master/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb#L46

Answer (score 0):

Usually the gem authors place links to the source in rubygems home page

```
https://rubygems.org/gems/<gem_name>
```

for your mentioned gems the source can be found

https://github.com/josh/ruby-coffee-script

and

https://github.com/nex3/sass